# Java Applet, GridLayout stretching TextFields Horizontally

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm writing a Java Applet and on one of my CardLayout Panels, the GridLayout within the `BorderLayout.CENTER` is streching the TextFields horizontally and vertically (this is ok because I can set vertical spacing between the parts of the grid). Can I stop the TextFields from being so wide and can I center the text within them?

Comment: *"`BorderLayout.CENTER` ..Can I stop the TextFields from being so wide(?)"*  Put them in `BorderLayout.LINE_START` or `BorderLayout.LINE_END` instead.  They will be stretched as wide as they need to be (as specified by the widest column), but have the entire height of the panel (less `PAGE_START` & `PAGE_END`).

Comment: @AndrewThompson
PAGE_END stopped the vertical stretching but then the text fields appear a lot lower in the applet. I might settle with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider nesting the JTextField-containing JPanels inside of another FlowLayout using JPanel. This way the FlowLayout using JPanel is the one that gets stretched while the JTextFields are sized based on what you set the int col property to be. Note that this will fail miserably if the nesting FlowLayout using JPanel is smaller than the preferredSize of its child JPanel.

Comment: The problem with this is I need to keep my TextFields as one column.
Thank you though.

Comment: @Harth: perhaps you shouldn't be using a GridLayout then as it is very inflexible. Perhaps you should be using a GridBagLayout or a MigLayout. Or quite possibly a JTable.

Comment: :-( I didn't want to use GridBagLayout because apparently it is more complicated but I guess I have to.